# Offsetting stroke shows as flat instead of pointy

Tags: adobe-illustrator, stroke

I want to cut a border exactly like the stroke.
So i applied offset. But the offset's end is not as pointy as the stroke.it ends up as  flat/smooth.

How can i make both the offset and the stroke to have same shape and end point[image]?

Comment: Hi there again! The pink line is a path with a brush stroke, right?

Comment: Have you tried checking your stroke's settings? (rounded, flat, pointy) Also, zooming in on the pointy end may provide more information (are the points properly joined, etc.)

Comment: @TheB Hello :) no i  use pen tool to draw a wavy shape  and then from stroke panel i choose 'width profile 1' and then it changes to a smooth one.

Comment: @curious no i did not. do they matter?? :O i think the problem caused by the offset not stroke setting....

Comment: It's a bug with variable strokes... I know it exists in CS6 and a couple early CC versions. No idea what version of AI you are using.

Comment: well it titled ''adobe illustrator 2020''...@Scott

Comment: i created an action where offset was in inch... but in this design i used pt. and applied tht action. can that cause problem?

Comment: Okay.. looks like they haven't fixed that bug yet. There are a couple placed wither the variable strokes "break" expected behavior. This is one, blends is another. You'll have to use a different method than using stroke profiles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This a workaround which doesn't involve making an offset.

I assume you made the curved shape as a stroke with Width Profile 1.  If not, then I suggest you create it that way.

1. Select the curved shape, copy it, and Paste in Back
2. Set the stroke colour to white, increase the stroke width
3. Use the Curvature Tool to click and drag the ends towards the edges of the circle.
4. Do *Object > Expand Appearance*
5. Now select both the black circle and white inner shape, open the Pathfinder and hit Minus Front to cut it out.

Example

[image]

Comment: Brilliant!!!! Jaw dropping solution!! <3 Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

To have the result that you want to achieve, it is more preferable that you use the stroke setting, instead of using offset. You will find under the stroke setting (I have it in german) how much the *max* of a corner should be. If you get some very long corners, then you must adjust the corners of the pink stroke with the pen tool.

[image]

Comment: Your sample shows a filled shape with a stroke, not an offset path.

Comment: yes, but that is the way that she has to make, if she wants the corner pointy. She doesn't have to stick with the offset, if she wants that result.

Comment: Then you should explain that in the answer. Because the miter limit won't really have any effect on single stroke with a profile assigned to it.

Comment: i cant attach ny picture in comment. so cant show you. that max option didn't change anything in my stroke. weird.... it remains same.

Comment: With the pen tool try to make the corner not that sharp, by moving the handles that are connected to the corner point.

Comment: okay. Thank you. am trying :)

Comment: @suraiyaabedin You can edit in images in your original question as an update, then refer to it in a comment :)

Comment: oh i see.. yes i have seen many people attach several pictures... but i could not.. i didnt know how to do it. Thank you for sharing this information. :)